# Security and JavaScript files containing a site's logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, security

Now that JavaScript libraries like jQuery are more popular than ever, .js files are starting to contain more and more of a site's logic. How and where it pulls data/information from, how that info is processed, etc. This isn't necessarily a bad thing, but I'm wondering to what extend this might be a security concern.

Of course the real processing of data still happens in the backend using PHP or some other language, and it is key that you make sure that nothing unwanted happens at that point. But just by looking at the .js of a site (that relies heavily on e.g. jQuery), it'll tell a person maybe more than you, as a developer, would like. Especially since every browser nowadays comes with a fairly extensive web developer environment or add-on. Even for a novice manipulating the DOM isn't that big of a deal anymore. And once you figure out what code there is, and how you might be able to influence it by editing the DOM, the 'fun' starts.

So my main concerns are:

1. I don't want everyone to be able to look at a .js file and see exactly (or rather: for a large part) how my site, web app or CMS works — what is there, what it does, how it does it, etc.
2. I'm worried that by 'unveiling' this information, people who are a lot smarter than I am figure out a way to manipulate the DOM in order to influence JavaScript functions they now know the site uses, possibly bypassing backend checks that I implemented (and thus wrongly assuming they were good enough).

I already use different .js files for different parts of e.g. a web app. But there's always stuff that has to be globally available, and sometimes this contains more than I'd like to be public. And since it's all "out there", who's to say they can't find those other files anyway.

I sometimes see a huge chuck of JavaScript without line breaks and all that. Like the compact jQuery files. I'm sure there are applications or tricks to convert your normal .js file to one long string. But if it can do that, isn't it just as easy to turn it back to something more readable (making it pointless except for saving space)?

Lastly I was thinking about whether it was possible to detect if a request for a .js file comes from the site itself (by including the script in the HTML), instead of a direct download. Maybe by blocking the latter using e.g. Apache's ModRewrite, it's possible to use a .js file in the HTML, but when someone tries to access it, it's blocked.

What are your thoughts about this? Am I overreacting? Should I split my JS as much as possible or just spend more time triple checking (backend) scripts and including more checks to prevent harm-doing? Or are there some best-practices to limit the exposure of JavaScripts and all the info they contain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing in your JavaScript should be a security risk, if you've set things up right. Attempting to access an AJAX endpoint one finds in a JavaScript file should check the user's permissions and fail if they don't have the right ones.

Having someone view your JavaScript is only a security risk if you're doing something broken like having calls to something like `/ajax/secret_endpoint_that_requires_no_authentication.php`, in which case your issue isn't insecure JavaScript, it's insecure code.

> I sometimes see a huge chuck of JavaScript without line breaks and all that. Like the compact jQuery files. I'm sure there are applications or tricks to convert your normal .js file to one long string. But if it can do that, isn't it just as easy to turn it back to something more readable (making it pointless except for saving space)?

This is generally minification (to reduce bandwidth usage), not obfuscation. It is easily reversible. There are obfuscation techniques that'll make all variable and function names something useless like "aa", "bb", etc., but they're reversible with enough effort.

> Lastly I was thinking about whether it was possible to detect if a request for a .js file comes from the site itself (by including the script in the HTML), instead of a direct download. Maybe by blocking the latter using e.g. Apache's ModRewrite, it's possible to use a .js file in the HTML, but when someone tries to access it, it's blocked.

It's possible to do this, but it's easily worked around by any half-competent attacker. **Bottom line:** nothing you send a non-privileged user's browser should *ever* be sensitive data.

Comment: @Michael Brooks Those should all be resolved on the server-side. User input shouldn't be sanitised on the client side, as it's untrusted.

Comment: There are cases when you need client side validation when user data does not hit server. For example, user sends a link to vulnerable swf hosted on sensitive domain with clickTAG=javascript to steal victim's cookies on sensitive domain. Here developer must call getURL only on input that starts with http(s). DOM based XSS is another case where userinput is used to say set innerHTML without any client side sanitization. Note that data that is used by server must be validated server side and we should not rely on any client side validation.

Comment: Haha, that was is funny fore more reasons that I care to explain online.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you should spend more time checking back-end scripts.  You have to approach the security problem as if the attacker is one of the key developers on your site, somebody who knows exactly how everything works. Every single URL in your site that does something to your database has to be protected to make sure that every parameter is within allowed constraints: a user can only change their own data, can only make changes within legal ranges, can only change things in a state that allows changes, etc etc etc. None of that has anything at all to do with what your Javascript looks like or whether or not anyone can read it, and jQuery has nothing at all to do with the problem (unless you've done it all wrong).

Remember: an HTTP request to your site can come from anywhere and be initiated by any piece of software in the universe. You have no control over that, and nothing you do to place restrictions on what clients can load what pages will have any effect on that. Don't bother with "REFERER" checks because the values can be faked. Don't rely on data scrubbing routines in your Javascript because those can be bypassed.

Answer (score 0):

There is free software that does [JavaScript Obfuscation](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Default.aspx).    Although there is not security though obscurity.  This does not prevent all attacks against your system. It does make it more difficult,  but not impossible for other people to rip off your JavaScript and use it.

There is also the issue of client side trust. By having a lot of logic on the client side the client is given the power to choose what it wants to execute.  For instance if you are escaping quote marks in JavaScript to protect against SQL Injection.  A Hacker is going to write exploit code to build his own HTTP request bypassing the escaping routines altogether.

[TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966) and [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) are commonly used by hackers to gain a deeper understanding of a Web Application.

JavaScript code alone **CAN** have vulnerabilities in it.  A good example is [DOM Based XSS](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS).  Although I admit this is not a very common type of XSS.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're right to be thinking about this stuff. It's a non-trivial and much misunderstood area of web application development.

In my opinion, the answer is that yes it *can* create more security issues, simply because (as you point out) the vectors for attack are increased. Fundamentally not much changes from a traditional (non JS) web application and the same best practises and approaches will server you very well. Eg, watching out for SQL injection, buffer overflows, response splitting, etc... You just have more places you need to watch out for it.

In terms of the scripts themselves, the issues around cross-domain security are probably the most prevalent. Research and learn how to avoid XSS attacks in particular, and also CSRF attacks.

JavaScript obfuscation is not typically carried out for security reasons, and you're right that it can be fairly easily reverse engineered. People do it, partially to protect intellectual property, but mainly to make the code download weight smaller.

I'd recommend Christopher Wells book published by O'Reilly called 'Securing Ajax Applications'.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a book by Billy Hoffman about Ajax security:

[http://www.amazon.com/Ajax-Security-Billy-Hoffman/dp/0321491939/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1266538410&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321491939)